# Django auth_views.PasswordResetView not sending custom email template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-email

I'm trying to send a custom email template with the reset token. But it keeps sending raw HTML no matter what I do. I have previous experience of doing exactly the same thing without any problem with the Django and Django rest framework.
Here's how I did it,

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls')),

    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

store/urls.py

```
...
path('password_reset',
      auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
            html_email_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_email.html',
            email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html',  
            ),
     name='password_reset'
    ),
```

folder structure

```
...
templates
|-- registration
     |-- html_password_reset_email.html 
     |-- password_reset_email.html
     |-- ...  
...
```

**Note:**

I tried deleting the `password_reset_email.html` template after that it sends the default Django email template.

Hoping for any guidance to solve the issue thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally days(3) of debugging I found my dumb mistake :(,

I was including all auth urls `path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` in my main `urls.py` file and re defining the `auth.urls` again in `store/urls.py` differently so the overriding doesn't happen correctly.

So, instead of,

```
path('password_reset',     # <<< here
      auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
       ...
      ),
     name='password_reset'
    ),
```

it should be,

```
 path('password_reset/',     # <<< here
      auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            ),
     name='password_reset'
    ),
```

---

Not gonna delete the question (^.^') #for_sake_of_dumb_fellows_like_me